# Changing Word document style in RMarkdown

Tags: ms-word, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown, officer

I am attempting to manually change the style within an R-markdown document. In the example below I have created a `reference_docx` with the style named `Highlight`

[image: img]

```
--- 
title: "My Title"
output:
  bookdown::word_document2:
    fig_caption: yes
    reference_docx: my_reference.docx
link-citations: no
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
---

# Here is Header 1

I want this text to be in red using the **Highlight** style from the reference document

I have tried 

<div style="Highlight">
This text is still not red
</div>
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I looked into the [officer](https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/) package but as far as I know this will only work after the document is rendered.

Comment: it should be `custom-style`, see http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#custom-styles

Comment: Perfect thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else finds this, here is the full answer. See the 'div' style below.

```
# Here is Header 1

I want this text to be in red using the **Highlight** style from the reference document

<div custom-style="Highlight">
This text should be red now.
</div>
```